# How do I install a real-time kernel with a patch I need to apply?

Tags: kernel, patch, realtime

I have ubuntu 12.04 with kernel 3.5. I have to install [the `RT_PREEMPT` patch](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) and I followed these steps:

```
sudo apt-get install kernel-package fakeroot build-essential libncurses5-dev
mkdir -p ~/tmp/linux-rt
cd ~/tmp/linux-rt
wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/linux-3.4.tar.bz2
wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/3.4/older/patch-3.4-rt7.patch.bz2
tar xjvf linux-3.4.tar.bz2
cd linux-3.4
patch -p1 < <(bunzip2 -c ../patch-3.4-rt7.patch.bz2)
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config && make oldconfig
make -j8
sudo make modules_install    
sudo make install
```

But while booting up the kernel it's showing the kernel panic:

> kernel panic - not syncing. Attempting to kill init!

I tried installing kernel 3.8 as well. But its showing error while executing the `make -j8` command.

Comment: Why not use the Lowlatancy Kernel that is already available in Ubuntu repositories ? Read more https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RealTime

Comment: Was the information above helpful to you? Do you still have this problem? Thank you!

Comment: I tried with Linux 3.6 and applied this patch also and it worked: http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/3.6/stable/patch-3.6.11.2.bz2

Comment: @SalihEmin I was asked to use the RT-patch. I didn't have choice over it.